installed build tools revision 34.0.0 is corrupted. (in Andrioid Studio 4.1)
I'm trying to run basic project but program shows
Installed Build Tools revision 34.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.
I'm using andriod studio 4.1 and here's other image that may help you
enter image description here
enter image description here
I removed sdk manager 34.0.0 but it won't works.
I also tried to fix it by change buildToolsVersion and targetSdkVersion but it made another error
Unsupported class file major version 61.
enter image description here

Please do post photos of a screen (and with wrong rotation). Every OS has built-in screenshot capability to create high-quality screenshots. And please don't post images of text error messages. Just copy and paste the error text.

The main problem is the two files missing in SDK build tool 34 that are
dx.bat dx.jar The solution is that these files are named d8 in the file location so changing their name to dx will solve the error.
For Windows
Step 1: Go to the location: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\34.0.0"
Rename the file name "d8.bat" to "dx.bat"
In the lib folder: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0\lib"
Rename the file name "d8.jar" to "dx.jar"
Remember AppData is a hidden folder. Turn on hidden items to see the AppData folder.
For macOS or Linux
Go to the location: "~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/34.0.0", and rename the file "d8.jar" to "dx.jar" or
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/34.0.0 \
  && mv d8 dx \
  && cd lib  \
  && mv d8.jar dx.jar


Maybe you should confirm your project's "sdk.dir" path first. It happened to me when I tried running my project on my WSL.
